# Webrtc Remote video stream freezes on app when starting screen sharing from chrome

Tags: java, android, webrtc, screensharing

We are using WebRTC library for p2p calling. Everything works fine but when started screen sharing while on call from Chrome (Switches media stream and renegotiate), remote stream on android app freezes(no audio, no video) but, Web is receiving both audio and video from the app.

When started screen sharing from android, it works fine on chrome. Tried many things, but couldn't find the solution.

Android WebRTC Version:

```
implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.26405'
```

After Starting Screen Sharing..
IceGatheringState: GATHERING
IceGatheringState: COMPLETE

IceConnectionState stays connected.

Tried using the latest version as well, but the same problem.